# I have low blood pressure. How do I know if I have exceeded the oral rehydration salts daily dose?

Tags: blood-pressure, water

The day time temperature ranges here from 41 to 43 degree Celsius. I have a white collar job and go to office on scooter with takes 30 minutes on one side.

I have low blood pressure. I take two packets of [these salts](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laminatorsprinters.com%2Fimages%2FORS.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laminatorsprinters.com%2Fmedical-packaging.html&docid=qL3dS9QUWen5CM&tbnid=L3NsnJ0VRdCaKM%3A&w=400&h=300&ei=H2VEVaTeJob_UtK7gPAL&ved=0CAIQxiAwAA&iact=c) daily.

How do I know if I have exceeded the oral rehydration salts daily dose?